# Sony "Camera Remote API Sample" error

Tags: sony

I am trying to develop an Android Application using the Sony Camera remote sample app as a learning point.

I have downloaded the Sony SDK, and have attempted to run the sample app. When I run it on a Nexus 5 phone, the application loads into the first Activity of the sample app. The device discovery process goes normally, and my camera appears on the list of discovered devices. When I press on the device to try and use its liveview functionality, the second activity loads up, but an error message occurs, "Failed to connect to device." Whats left is a black screen, and the two buttons on the left side (Take Picture, and Start movie recording). The WiFi connection between the camera and phone is still intact, and the camera still appears on the discovered devices list.

The camera I am using is the HDR-AS15. Is there anything on my end that I can do? Does anyone else get a similar issue when trying to run sony's sample app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have the latest firmware installed on your ActionCam.  This error can occur if you are using older FW that does not support the Camera Remote API.